# Append to list of files in bash

Tags: bash, list

so I'm trying to get a simple bash script to continuously read a directory and update a list of files to play through a command. However, I'm having some trouble thinking out the logic in it. What I need to do is put the current items in the directory into the list, have each item in the directory run through a program, and when a new item comes in, just append it to the list. I'm attempting to use `inotifywait` but can't seem to think of the proper logic. I may need it to run in the background, as the process that is running on these files will run before `inotifywait` is read again, at which point it will not pick up any new files that have been added as it only checks when it runs. Here's the code so hopefully it makes more sense.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Initial check to see if files are converted.
if [ ! -d "/home/pi/rpitx/converted" ]; then
  echo "Converted directory does not exist, cannot play!"
  exit 1
fi
CYAN='\e[36m'
NC='\e[39m'
LGREEN='\e[92m'
#iterate through directory first and act upon each item
for f in $FILES
do
  echo -e "${CYAN}Now playing ${f##*/}...${NC}"
  #Figure out a way to always watch directory even when it is playing
  inotifywait -m /home/pi/rpitx/converted -e create -e moved_to | 
    while read path action file; do
      echo -e "${LGREEN}New file found: ${CYAN}${file}${NC}"
      FILES+=($file)
  done
  # take action on       each file. $f store current file name
  sudo ./rpitx -m RF -i "${f}" -f 101100
done
exit 0
```

So for example. if `rpitx` is currently playing something, and a file is converted, it won't pick up the latest file and add it to the list, nor will it make it since it's always reading. Is there a way to get `inotifywait` to run in the background of this script somehow? Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of the `for f in $FILES`, piping the result of `inotifywait` to a `while` loop is all you need. The format is `inotifywait ... | while read; do ...stuff... done`. If you need your list of `FILES` filled before you call `inotifywait`, fill it first. `inotifywait` is already watching for new files, you don't loop it.

Comment: That's what I thought about doing, but when I try just using `inotifywait ... | while read path action file | do stuff` it doesn't pick up the files that are currently in the directory that need to be acted upon as well, unless I'm missing something. Just saw the edit, will get back to you shortly here!

Comment: Okay so one last problem here I guess since I don't completely understand (new to inotifywait and looking into it more), is that I need the command rpitx to play on all current files in the directory (aka everything in `$FILES` at that beginning moment). The problem is that a file can appear while it's playing those files. Any more ideas? I'll take a look in the morning as it's pretty late here and it's probably impeding my progress...

Comment: It's a 2-part problem. If you need to process all files that exist on script invocation, do it, then call `inotifywait` to watch for, and act on, changes. Depending on how long your `...stuff...` takes to execute, there is a possibility that a new file will hit and won't be appended until your current `...stuff...` completes, it's not an *atomic* process, but it is more than sufficient for all practical purposes.

Comment: Hmm alright, well thank you for the effort here, I'll see if I can think of a different solution other than bash then, kudos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite a difficult problem to get 100% perfect, but it is possible to get pretty close.

It is easy to get all the files in a directory, and it is easy to use `inotifywait` to get iteratively informed of new files being placed into the directory. The issue is getting the two to be consistent. If `inotifywait` isn't started until all the files have been processed (or even just listed), then you might miss new files created between the listing and the invocation of `inotifywait`. If, on the other hand, you start `inotifywait` first, then a file created after the invocation of `inotifywait` and the extraction of the current file list will be listed twice.

Since it is easier to filter duplicates than notice orphans, the recommended approach is the second one.

As a first approximation, we could ignore the duplicate problem on the assumption that the window of vulnerability is pretty short and so it is probably unlikely to happen. This simplifies the code, but it's not that difficult to track and eliminate duplicates: we could, for example, store each filename as the key in an associative array, ignoring the file if the key already exists.

We need three processes: one to execute `inotifywait`; one to produce the list of initial files; and one to handle each file as it is identified. So the basic structure of the code will be:

```
list_new_files |
{ list_existing_files; pass_through; } |
while read action file; do
  handle -r "$action" "$file"
done
```

Note that the second process first produces the existing files, and then calls `pass_through`, which reads from standard input and writes to standard output, thus passing through the files being discovered by `list_new_files`. Since pipes have a finite capacity, it is possible that the execution of `list_existing_files` will block a few times (if there are lots of existing files and handling them takes a long time), so when `pass_through` finally gets executed, it could have quite a bit of queued-up input to pass through. That doesn't matter, unless the first pipe also fills up, which will happen if a large number of new files are created. And that still won't matter as long as `inotifywait` doesn't lose notifications while it is blocked on a write. (This may actually be a problem, since the manpage for `inotifywait` on my system includes in the "BUGS" section the note, "It is assumed the inotify event queue will never overflow." We could fix the problem by inserting another process which carefully buffers `inotifywait`'s output, but that shouldn't be necessary unless you intend to flood the directory with lots of files.)

Now, let's examine each of the functions in turn.

`list_new_files` could be just the call to `inotifywait` from your original script:
      inotifywait -m /home/pi/rpitx/converted -e create -e moved_to

Listing existing files is also easy. Here's one simple solution:

```
 printf "%s\n" /home/pi/rpitx/converted/*
```

However, that will print out the full file path, which is different from the output from `inotifywait`. To make them the same, we `cd` into the directory in order to do the listing. Since we might not actually want to change the working directory, we use a subshell by surrounding the commands inside parentheses:

```
( cd /home/pie/rpitx/converted; printf "%s\n" *; )
```

The `printf` just prints its arguments each on a separate line. Since glob-expansions are *not* word-split or recursively glob-expanded, this is safe against whitespace or metacharacters in filenames, *except newline characters*. Filenames with newline characters are pretty rare; for now, I'll ignore the issue but I'll indicate how to handle it at the end.

Even with the change indicated above, the output from these two commands is not compatible: the first one outputs three things on each line (directory, action, filename), and the second one just one thing (the filename). In the listing below, you'll see how we modify the format to `printf` and introduce a format for `inotifywait` in order to make the outputs fully compatible, with the "action" for existing files set to `EXISTING`.

`pass_through` could, in theory, just be `cat`, and that's how I've coded it below. However, it is important that it operate in line-buffered mode; otherwise, nothing will happen until "enough" files have been written by `list_existing_files`. On my system, `cat` in this configuration works perfectly; if that doesn't work for you or you don't want to count on it, you could write it explicitly as a while read loop:

```
pass_through() {
  while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done
}
```

Finally, `handle` is essentially the code from the original post, but modified a bit to take the new format into account, and to do the right thing with action `EXISTING`.

```
# Colours. Note the use of `$'...'` to actually store the code,
# thereby avoiding the need to later reinterpret backslash sequences
CYAN=$'\e[36m'
NC=$'\e[39m'
LGREEN=$'\e[92m'
converted=/home/pi/rpitx/converted

list_new_files() {
  inotifywait -m "$converted" -e create -e moved_to --format "%e %f"
}

# Note the use of ( ) around the body instead of { }
# This is the same as `{( ... )}'; it makes the `cd` local to the function.
list_existing_files() (
  cd "$converted"
  printf "EXISTING %s\n" *
)

# Invoked as `handle action filename`
handle() {
  case "$1" in
    EXISTING) 
      echo "${CYAN}Now playing ${2}...${NC}"
    ;;
    *)
       echo "${LGREEN}New file found: ${CYAN}${file}${NC}"
    ;;
  esac
  sudo ./rpitx -m RF -i "${f}" -f 101100
}

# Put everything together
list_new_files |
{ list_existing_files; cat; } |
while read -r action file; do handle "$action" "$file"; done
```

What if we thought a filename might have a newline character in it? There are two "safe" characters which could be used to delimit the filenames, in the sense that they cannot appear inside a filename. One is <kbd>/</kbd>, which can obviously appear in a path, but cannot appear in a simple filename, which is what we're working with here. The other one is the `NUL` character, which cannot appear inside a filename at all, but can sometimes be a bit annoying to deal with.

Normally, faced with this problem, we would use a `NUL`, but that depends on the various utilities we're using allowing the separation of data with `NUL` instead of newline. That's not the case for `inotifywait`, which always outputs a newline after a notification line. So in this case it seems simpler to use a <kbd>/</kbd>. First we modify the formats:

```
  inotifywait -m "$converted" -e create -e moved_to --format "%e %f/"

  printf "%s/\n" *
```

Now, when we're reading the lines, we need to read until we find a line ending with <kbd>/</kbd> (and remember to remove it). `read` doesn't allow two-character line terminators, so we need to accumulate the lines ourselves:

```
while read -r action file; do
  # If file doesn't end with a slash, we need to read another line
  while [[ file != */ ]] && read -r line; do
    file+=$'\n'"$line"
  done
  # Remember to remove the trailing slash
  handle "$action" "${file%/}"
done
```

Comment: Bravo for going through the effort to do things the Right Way, particularly when using tools that make it unnecessarily hard.

Comment: Oh my Lord this is an amazing write up! Thank you so much for going through this for me, I had no idea it would be such a complex (imo) problem to go through in order to concurrently read and add to a list in bash! Thanks again!

Comment: @phlex: concurrency is always tricky. Normally I solve problems like this differently: I use a second directory with (hard) links to the files to be worked on. The notify loop puts creates a hard link for each discovered file, and I add a hard link for every existing file as well. That can't produce a duplicate because the hard link will fail and I just ignore failures. So now I have a temporary directory full of (expendable) links; the original files are safely elsewhere. Then I can repeatedly process a random file and delete the link so that it doesn't get processed again.